# Corda 4.7 QueryCriteria, LinearStateQueryCriteria

Tags: blockchain, corda

I have below query criteria to fetch State based on linearId. I am trying below code

```
//query criteria
QueryCriteria queryCriteria = new LinearStateQueryCriteria(
    null,
    ImmutableList.of(UUID.fromString(linearId)) 
);
```

However, I am getting a compile time error asking to change `QueryCriteria` to `QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria`. If I do that, then `vaultService.queryBy()` does not accept the `queryCriteria` and throws a compile time error.

[image: Compile Time Error]

As per documentation, [API: Vault Query - Custom queries in Java](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/api-vault-query.html#custom-queries-in-java) it should have worked. Can someone help ?

Comment: I tried with powershell the same code, and deploy nodes ran fine. It seems like #IntelliJ Editor issue.

Comment: I got Intellij 2020.3.4 installed via Jetbrains ToolBox and the same code works fine there. It is definitely IntelliJ IDE problem. Corda does not work in 2021.x IntelliJ version

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Downgrading intellij also solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

glad to see you figured it out, even though I'm not sure why IJ would flag the wrong error. In any event, here's my go-to code sample of making a query on a linear state.

link attached:

https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/obligation/flows/IOUSettleFlow.java#L57-L62

Comment: Yes... Even I am not able to figure out why, so raised a BUG with JetBrains. Here's the link https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-19699